# How can I detect if a table row in mySQL has files or not?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table `friends` in my SQL database:

```
╔════╦═══════╦═══════╦═══════╗
║ id ║ name1 ║ name2 ║ name3 ║
╠════╬═══════╬═══════╬═══════╣
║ 1  ║ fred  ║       ║       ║
║ 2  ║ tom   ║       ║       ║
╚════╩═══════╩═══════╩═══════╝
```

Now I want to detect if `name2` has any content or not.

```
$sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT name2 FROM friends WHERE id = '$id'");
                            $sql->execute();
                            $result = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                            if (!$result) {
                            echo "there is no content";
                            } else {
                            echo "there is content";
                            };
```

But right now I have the problem, that I get for id `1` and `2`: `there is content` and for id `3`: `there is no content`. But for `name2`  there should actually always be `there is no content`. What did I do wrong?

Comment: `if(!$result['name2']) {`

Comment: @Daan: Great! Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your column is empty (not null, but '' ) the

```
if(!result)
```

will be evaluated to false.

Try:

```
if(!result || result == '')
```